# Which socket programming is best (TCP/UDP)?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp

My client program wants to send a huge file to the server and in return the server program returns a double or triple sized file.

My question is, which approach should I use? Either TCP or UDP.

Comment: Do you have to use a socket?  HTTP, FTP have each been suggested or you could directly push the file across the network.

Comment: Yes, I want the answer only regarding socket programming and I think I got it.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

UDP programmin but it will be difficult to implement

Comment: Unlikely. File transfer kinda needs reliable transmission.

Comment: Not really, since UDP is a protocol that does **not** guarantee that the packets come in, or come in in order. It's definitely not 'best and easy to implement'.

Comment: TCP Doesn't guarantee delivery either, not saying that UDP is the better choice but I think that should be clarified.

Comment: i know that TCP is Better but for large file UDP perform better as UDP can send large packet in one go

Comment: @Tim You should read up on TCP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: @Ashish Could be that it performs better, but the point is, it is not easier to implement.

Comment: @Ashish unless it is dropped or fragmented.  The larger the packet, the more likely it will be dropped.  BTW a single UDP packet cannot be more than 64 KB, which might be a problem if you have files larger than this.

Comment: @Ashish "Large packet in one go"? What are you *talking* about?

Comment: @mike dude see AJ comment chrylis post thats y i told him to use UDP

Comment: @chrylis UDP supports packets of up to 64 KB, whereas TCP is typically 1.5 KB of 9 KB. While you can send 64 KB packets, there is no guarantee it will be supported by your network infrastructure and arrive of course.

Comment: @peter lawrey dude see AJ comment chrylis post thats y i told him to use UDP

Comment: @Mike, There is no way that delivery can be guaranteed as there are two many points of failure. To write code that pushes out a message and assumes success is asking for disaster - I've seen it.  For every developer that is out there that believes that, there is another that has to account for someone else's misconception.

Comment: The generally accepted UDP payload size across the Interment is 534 bytes. Within an Ethernet it is limited by the Ethernet frame size of around 1500 bytes. Within a single host you can achieve 65507 bytes. Merely naming one protocol over another without giving any reasons doesn't constitute an answer

Answer (score 5):

You could utilize [**FTP (File Transfer Protocol)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) for your use case.
It is very common and you can use it with java to get or to upload
files to the FTP server.

Also take a look at this question on SO: [**File upload in Java through FTP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739153/file-upload-in-java-through-ftp)

---

If you still want to implement it yourself, I would recommend using **TCP**, since it offers you some services:

- Ordered data transfer — the destination host rearranges according to sequence number
- Retransmission of lost packets — any cumulative stream not acknowledged is retransmitted
- Error-free data transfer

  <sup>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer</sup>

Comment: Ordering is not the issue. Issue is a huge file.

Comment: Ordering will be an issue if you use UDP, because UDP does not guarentee the order. The points I listed are things that TCP has over UDP.

Comment: @AJ. Ordering is a *big* issue. Just use a servlet; this is a difficult problem that's been solved already, and you don't understand the issues involved.

Comment: @AJ. Order matters if you want the file to arrive in the same order it left.

Answer (score 4):

This question is too broad, but the answer is *probably* TCP; if you're needing to transfer a file, TCP provides ordering and retransmission services that UDP doesn't, and there's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Along those lines, though, why reinvent HTTP? This sounds like a classic case for using a Web server.

Comment: my question is about a large file may be upto 1gb or more.

Comment: File size has nothing to do with it. I just downloaded a 1.2GB DBpedia dump over HTTP tonight, and HTTP provides nice things like resuming partial downloads that you don't have to reinvent.

Comment: In that case, you need TCP.  UDP is less reliable if you send more than 532 bytes. In fact it is not reliable if you send less.

Comment: @chrylis It matters if you used UDP and tried to send the whole file in one packet as Ashish suggests.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I really don't think that a 64k file counts as "large" in this day and age.

Comment: @chrylis I agree with Peter Lawrey.

Comment: @chrylis I find large, huge, fast, quick to be *very* subjective even to an order of magnitude.